# Google Map GEO Results

Tags: google-maps, geolocation

I'm getting really frustrated with Google geo results and hope someone can advise me the best was to go.

I have created a AutoSuggest feature where you can start typing the address and Google will respond with suggestions. User then selects and address to move on.

But before I want them to continue on the next page I want to validate their selection. I would have thought this will be easy as we are only checking against what Google has already given. But when I do my validation lookup it displays no results.

Some example code:

Lets say I picked from the suggestion this address: Suffield, CT 06078, USA

Then on validation I do a second lookup with this address ie.

```
$string = "Suffield, CT 06078, USA";    
echo 'http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?output=json&oe=utf8&gl=us&sensor=false&key=[MyKey]&q='.urlencode($string).'';
```

It gives me Error code 602 (G_GEO_UNKNOWN_ADDRESS)

How can it not be found when its given me the address?

How I can get around this?

Comment: Looks like it works if you remove either the state or the zip code.  I don't know why...

Comment: Is this **maps.google.com/maps/geo?** API deprecated?

Answer (score 3):

You're right. That is quite strange.

Note that it does work when you remove the space between CT and 06078:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=Suffield,+CT06078,+USA&output=csv&sensor=false
```

The above returns 41.9817631,-72.6506462. ([Link to Google Maps](http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=41.9817631,-72.6506462&sll=37.0625,-95.677068&sspn=59.076726,104.501953&ie=UTF8&t=h&z=17))

---

Reverse geocoding those coordinates with:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=41.9817631,-72.6506462&output=csv&sensor=false
```

returns:

```
200,4,"Suffield, CT, USA"
```

Comment: Wiered by removing a space works? May have to have Yahoo API backup and them maybe removing the space and trying again

Answer (score 1):

It's really strange, to be sure, but I was able to validate the address using the full state name.

Doesn't work:

> http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?output=json&oe=utf8&gl=us&sensor=false&key=[MyKey]&q=Suffield,%20CT%2006078

Does Work:

> http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?output=json&oe=utf8&gl=us&sensor=false&key=[MyKey]&q=Suffield,%20Connecticut%2006078

And yes, the address they provided to you doesn't work in their own system.  That being said, searching for Hartford, CT DOES work.  It appears there may be a listing discrepency in their data whereby Suffield + CT returns false results.